# Grouping objects by keys and creating a tree

Tags: java, c#

I have a list of Row items:

```
Row{
   Level1: "A"
   Level2: "B"
   Level3: "C"
   name: "item1"
}
Row{
   Level1: "A"
   Level2: "B"
   Level3: null
   name: "item2"
}
Row{
   Level1: "D"
   Level2: null
   Level3: null
   name: "item3"
}
```

I want to return a list of objects that are like:

```
[{text: "A", items: [ 
     {text: "B", items: [
          {text: "C", items: [
              text: "item1", items:[]]}, 
          {text: "item2", items: []}}]}, 
 {text: "D", items: [{text: "item3", items: []}]}
]
```

Basically, "name" is the last level. In reality, there's like 10 levels so I want to code something that is extendable to an arbitrary number of levels. I have written a model for the Item() object which looks like

```
class Item{string text, Item[] items}
```

If I was constructing just a json/dictionary I think it would be pretty simple (iterate over the Row objects, iterate over each key, check if it's already in my "final" dict, if I hit a null level then break and add the last level/item). I want to return a Item[] list though, which means I need to construct Item() objects but keep adding to Item.items..

Anyone have ideas for a way to achieve this?

Comment: So what is the input, json ?

Comment: The input is a list of Row objects - Row[]. The output is a list of item objects - Item[]

Comment: Would it be best to have actual C# / Java sample data instead of json? Also you want us to design a solution with concrete properties that are arbitrary, would you like us to use reflection ?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by Java sample data.. I thought I gave sample data - its not a json, though maybe its confusing because I used curly brackets